# Sending email on behalf of another user

Tags: c#, gmail-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

Currently I have used GMail API (OAuth Credential for Web) to read and send email messages. How can we send email on behalf of another user (i.e. noreply@example.com)?

In enterprise application, do we need to use service account for reading specific user's mail labels, messages and send email on behalf of that user?

Comment: GMAIL requires the email FROM address and the credentials to be from the same account.  If you are using default credentials than the user that is logged in must also be the same email FROM address

Comment: Have you checked [this method of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/create) for sending emails with the ```from``` field with an Alias? Do you mind using aliases or you do not want that at all even if it ends up with the same name as intended?

Comment: i checked documentation link given above but it only applies to Service account concept. I don't think it would be applicable to user OAUTH credential scheme. However; with Service account approach can we access the gmail user's mail box other than service account mail box ?

Comment: What do you mean by *can we access the gmail user's mail box other than service account mail box*? Using a service account you will be able to send emails with Aliases. This emails will be within the service account sent inbox for messages and if someone replies to these messages it will end up in the service account mailbox unless you set up a forwarding email address. Let me know if this has clarified anything.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Even i used to believe what you said. however; i feel somewhat doubtful that might be possible some how. I know it sounds like bit odd. its better to clear things.

Comment: What do you mean by can we access the gmail user's mail box other than service account mail box?

Comment: i meant that whether using service account approach whether we can access other user's mail box items or not

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Indeed you **CAN** send and read the mailbox of other user's **in your domain** with the Gmail API using a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-role) with [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation).

You will need to grant the service account with the `Project Role` of `Owner` using the domain wide authorization.

Apart from the official documentation linked above, [here is a tutorial](https://medium.com/lyfepedia/sending-emails-with-gmail-api-and-python-49474e32c81f) on how to send emails on behalf of other users using service accounts. To read from their mailbox you would follow the same process. [Here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings) is more information on mail delegation in case you are interested.

> NOTE : in order to do this your service account **must** be in the same domain as the user's email you are trying to send and read messages from.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)